# Play or A-B repeat a slice of a Youtube

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

hi any one can help how i can add youtube reapeat bare in video
demo : http://youtubeonrepeat.com/watch/?v=bbEoRnaOIbs!
i want the code ofthis loop

Comment: Have you done any research your self or tested anything? Have you looked at that page's source?

Comment: youtube has a lot of documentation on how to put their videos with certain features disabled/enabled on other sites.

Answer (score 0):

You need a double-handled slider (aka "range slider") for this, jQuery provides [one](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range). Then add a timer which repeatedly monitors the video's current time and does the necessary seek operations.

Checkout [AB Loop Player](https://agrahn.gitlab.io/ABLoopPlayer/) and its source code on GitLab for a working example.

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
  <object width="847" height="499.7">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/8NVzuqhFxJ4">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/8NVzuqhFxJ4?version=2&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1;" type=
    "application/x-shockwave-flash" width="847" height="499.7" allowscriptaccess="always"
    allowfullscreen="true">
  </object>
```